# How to edit multi picklist after "after update" trigger runs?

Tags: apex

I am running a trigger after update. It looks at a multi-picklist for the values. Once done, I want to reset that multi-picklist to null. How to do this?

Comment: You can only do this in before insert that field exist on same object on which trigger is written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit an inserted or updated object during an after trigger.  However, what you could do is store the value of your picklist in a static `Map` in the before trigger, then reference it in the after trigger.  Note that the `Map` must be defined in a separate class.

```
public class myTriggerHandler
{
    public static Map<ID, String> multiPicklistValues = new Map<ID, String>();

    public static storeAndClearMultiPicklistValues(List<mySObject> objs)
    {
        for (mySObject s : objs)
        {
            multiPicklistValues.put(s.ID, s.mPicklistField__c);
            s.mPicklistField__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your after trigger, you can simply retrieve the old picklist values with `multiPicklistValues.get(trigger.New[i].ID)`.